# Number of maximal cliques in a ($2C_4$, $C_5$, $P_5$)-free graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, clique

So far, I have found out that chordal graphs have [linear number of maximal cliques](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/75/531/CS-TR-75-531.pdf) with respect to the number of vertices.
In general case, it is exponential.

I am trying to determine whether the number of maximal cliques in a $(2C_4, C_5,P_5)$-free graph with respect to the number of vertices.

In a $(2C_4, C_5,P_5)$-free graph, the largest induced cycle is of length 4, and no two induced 4-cycles are edge-disjoint.

Is there a paper that mentions such result?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47691/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/117238/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856299/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The famous graph (the complement of the disjoint union of $n/3$ triangles) with $3^{n/3}$ maximal cliques is $K_1 \cup K_2$-free, and thus has none of $2C_4$, $C_5$, $P_5$ as an induced subgraph.

https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02760024

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know whether it is still exponential when two induced triandlges cannot be edge-disjoint in the complement, i.e. $(K_{3,3}, 2C_4, C_5, P_5)$-free? I guess the answer is still yes, but I cannot see it directly.

Comment: As you guessed, the answer is still yes. The complement of the disjoint union of $n/2$ copies of $K_2$'s has $2^{n/2}$ maximal cliques.

Comment: So basically, whenever 4-cycles are involved, it is most likely that the number of maximal cliques is exponential.

Comment: The following paper supports such an intuition.
https://doi.org/10.1002/net.3230230308

Comment: Can you please be kind enough to post this answer here as well? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-2c-4-c-5-p-5-free-graph
I have a bounty going on there and it would be a shame if 100 rep was wasted :)

Comment: Done! I posted a slightly expanded answer there.